# Show $\int_{0}^{-x}\frac{t^n}{1-t}dt=(-1)^{n+1}\int_{0}^{x}\frac{t^n}{1+t}dt$ for $-1<x<1$.

Tags: calculus

Show $\int_{0}^{-x}\frac{t^n}{1-t}dt=(-1)^{n+1}\int_{0}^{x}\frac{t^n}{1+t}dt$ for $-1<x<1$.

Maybe I'm not thinking straight today but I can't seem to justify the above.

Comment: Seems that expansion into power series could do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: use the change of variable $t = -u$.